# Get the last array index from a JSON array - laravel 5.2

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel-5

I have a leader board for the Halo 5 API, and for each leader board, I have the top 100 users for a particular Playlist, for **this season**. The problem I'm having is I have to make a call to get this data, and this is what it requests:

```
// $baseURL = 'https://www.haloapi.com/stats/{title}/player-leaderboards/csr/{seasonId}/{playlistId}[?count]';

$baseURL = 'https://www.haloapi.com/stats/h5/player-leaderboards/csr/8787875e-d2c6-4c50-b949-38e22728f9f4/c98949ae-60a8-43dc-85d7-0feb0b92e719?count=100';
```

One of the elements it requests is the season-ID. Every month this season ID changes, because a new season starts. So I have to update this every month, which is not efficient.

I need to loop through the season array and get the last array index for that loop so I can get the ID for that season. Then I wont have to update every time, it will do it automatically.

Here is the call I make to get all the Seasons:

```
public function getSeason() {

        $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

        $baseURL = 'https://www.haloapi.com/metadata/h5/metadata/seasons';

        $res = $client->request('GET', $baseURL, [
            'headers' => [
                'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' => 'MY KEY'
            ]
        ]);

        if ($res->getStatusCode() == 200) {
            return $result = json_decode($res->getBody());
        } elseif ($res->getStatusCode() == 404) {
            return $result = redirect()->route('/');
        }

        return $res;
    }
```

This is how I DD it right now:

```
    public function getSeasonsArray($Seasons) {
        $x = $Seasons;
        dd($x);
    }
```

And this is the result:

```
array:6 [▼
  0 => {#204 ▶}
  1 => {#209 ▶}
  2 => {#216 ▶}
  3 => {#222 ▶}
  4 => {#228 ▶}
  5 => {#234 ▼
    +"playlists": array:5 [▶]
    +"iconUrl": "https://content.halocdn.com/media/Default/forums/badges/thumbs/badge-enlisted-45x45-0d172751d2aa4d4691cf966c111b9ece.png"
    +"name": "May 2016 Season"
    +"startDate": "2016-05-02T17:00:00Z"
    +"endDate": null
    +"isActive": true
    +"id": "8787875e-d2c6-4c50-b949-38e22728f9f4"
    +"contentId": "8787875e-d2c6-4c50-b949-38e22728f9f4"
  }
]
```

How can I loop through this array and get the last index of this array to get the ID of the season.

---

This is how I make my call to get a particular playlist for this season:

```
public function getTeamArenaLeaderboards() {


        $Seasons =  $this->getSeason();
        $SeasonsArray =  $this->getSeasonsArray($Seasons);


        $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

        // $baseURL = 'https://www.haloapi.com/stats/{title}/player-leaderboards/csr/{seasonId}/{playlistId}[?count]';

        $baseURL = 'https://www.haloapi.com/stats/h5/player-leaderboards/csr/8787875e-d2c6-4c50-b949-38e22728f9f4/c98949ae-60a8-43dc-85d7-0feb0b92e719?count=100';

        $res = $client->request('GET', $baseURL, [
            'headers' => [
                'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key' => 'MY KEY'
            ]
        ]);

        if ($res->getStatusCode() == 200) {
            return $result = json_decode($res->getBody());
        } elseif ($res->getStatusCode() == 404) {
            return $result = redirect()->route('/');
        }

        return $res;
    }
```

/************* EDIT ********************

Got it working by doing this:

```
 public function getTeamArenaLeaderboards() {

        // Get all the Seasons
        $Seasons =  $this->getSeason();

        // Get the last Season of the array
        $lastSeason = end($Seasons);

        // Get the ID of the last Season
        $last = $lastSeason->id;


        $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();


 $baseURL = 'https://www.haloapi.com/stats/h5/player-leaderboards/csr/' . $last .'/c98949ae-60a8-43dc-85d7-0feb0b92e719?count=100';
```

Comment: Would [`array_pop`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) work for you?

Comment: I think that you could just use `key(end($arr))` to get what you want. Unless it's not the index of the last member that you want and I misunderstood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [end()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php):

```
echo end($Seasons)['id'];
```

Or for earlier PHP versions:

```
$last = end($Seasons);
echo $last['id'];
```

Comment: Alright I got the last ID of the array, now I have to insert it into the header. Give me a sec.

Comment: Yes, Thank You. I got it to work.